# print the rest of input along with matching line

Tags: grep

I am new to linux and I am experimenting with basic terminal commands. I found out that I can list all users using `compgen -u` but what if I only want to display the bottom line outputs ?
Ok lets say the output of `compgen -u` goes like this:

```
extra
extra
extra
extra
extra
extra
extra
extra
extra
John
William
Kate
Harold
```

I can only use grep to find a single text (ex. `compgen -u | grep John`). But what if I want to use grep to display John as well as all the remaining entries after it ?

Answer (score 1):

`sed` or `awk` solution would be easier, but if you can only use `grep`, then the option `--after-context` (or `-A`) might do:

```
grep -A 5 John file
```

The drawback is that you need to know the number of lines to display after the matching (or use an arbitrary big number for the rest of the file).

Answer (score 0):

**`compgen -u | grep -A$(compgen -u|  wc -l)  John`**

Explanation:

```
From man grep

       -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
                  Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines.  Places a line containing a group separator (described under --group-separator) between
                  contiguous groups of matches.
```

```
    grep -A -- print number of rows after pattern 

    $() -- Execute unix command 

    compgen -u|  wc -l --> Get total number of rows of output of command.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following one-liner :

```
n=$( compgen -u | grep -n John | head -1 | cut -d ":" -f 1 ) && compgen -u | tail -n +$n
```

This finds out the line number for first occurrence of John, and prints everything starting that line.